# from text file into 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays

I don't have idea how make functional program and I wanna transfer text file into 2D array.

Thank you for answers

This is content of my text file:

```
0000000011
0011100000
0000001110
1000011100
1000000000
0000111111
1000001100
1000000000
1000011000
1000001111
```

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[,] map = new int[10, 10];

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"Lode.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            **WHAT I SHOULD PUT HERE**

        }
    }            
    reader.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do following (code with my comments):

```
var map = new int[10, 10];

using (var reader = new StreamReader("Lode.txt"))  // using will call close automatically
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();  // read one line from file
        for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            map[i, j] = Int32.Parse(line[j].ToString());  // get one symbol from current line and convert it to int
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well my console app is empty after this code. I don't know why

Comment: what do you mean? did you try to print  `map` to console after initializing?

Comment: Well, maybe I am dumb, but I don't know how… I am quite beginner

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(map[i, j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

Comment: Thank you for help… I wonder If I can hide this "playing board" and after the hit they appear individually.

Comment: I am ok with your answer… Thank you…. Just there is some option how to change a "word" when is everything loaded from .txt? For example: Change "0" for "2" not in text document but from program.cs

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a little LINQ as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string filePath = @"Lode.txt";

    // Read file contents and store it into a local variable
    string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

    /* Split by CR-LF in a windows system, 
       then convert it into a list of chars 
       and then finally do a int.Parse on them
    */

    int[][] map = fileContents.Split('\r', '\n')
                 .Select(x => x.ToList())
                 .Select(x => x.Select(y => int.Parse(new string(y, 1))).ToArray())
                 .ToArray();

}
```